# Angular-Interceptor: Cancel outgoing http requests on access token expiration and retry them on completion

Tags: angular, jwt, interceptor

I have implemented a way to retry failed requests in my project using  a queue to intercept requests that happen while a token is refreshing to store them and retry them on successful refresh. This works fine, but there are cases where multiple such requests occur at the same time and instead of just letting them execute and fail with 401, I would like to cancel them before they are handled and re-play them when the token has been successfully refreshed. Below is my current implementation so far that handles the failed requests, which I would like to modify. Any ideas are welcome.

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap, filter, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LocalStorage } from './local-storage';
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      const accessToken = LocalStorage.getAccessToken();
      if (accessToken) {
        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken) });
      }
   
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private isRefreshing = false;
  private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  private requestQueue: Array<{ request: HttpRequest<any>; next: HttpHandler }> = [];

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 401 && !this.isSpecialCase(req.url)) {
          return this.handle401Error(req, next);
        } else if (this.isSpecialCase(req.url) && (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403)) {
          localStorage.removeItem('user');
          localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return throwError(() => error);
        } else {
          return throwError(() => error);
        }
      })
    );
  }
  private addAuthentication(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string | null): HttpRequest<any> {
    if (token) {
      return request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });
    }
    return request;
  }

  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        tap((tokenResponse) => {
          const newToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
          if (newToken) {
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(newToken);
            this.isRefreshing = false;
            this.processQueuedRequests(newToken);
          } else {
            this.logoutAndRedirect();
          }
        }),
        switchMap((tokenResponse) => {
          return next.handle(this.addAuthentication(request, tokenResponse.accessToken));
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          return this.logoutAndRedirect();
        })
      );
    } else {
      this.queueRequest(request, next);
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter((token) => token !== null),
        take(1),
        switchMap((jwt) => {
          return next.handle(this.addAuthentication(request, jwt));
        })
      );
    }
  }

  private queueRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    this.requestQueue.push({ request, next });
  }

  private processQueuedRequests(newToken: string) {
    while (this.requestQueue.length) {
      const queuedRequest = this.requestQueue.shift();
      if (queuedRequest) {
        queuedRequest.next.handle(this.addAuthentication(queuedRequest.request, newToken));
      }
    }
  }

  private logoutAndRedirect(): Observable<never> {
    this.isRefreshing = false;
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return throwError(() => new HttpErrorResponse({ status: 401 }));
  }

  private isSpecialCase(url: string): boolean {
    return url.includes('auth/refresh') || url.includes('auth/logout') || url.includes('login');
  }
}
```

Comment: you have 401 else handling which would retry requests. why do you need the queue?